# What packages do I need in order to install scikit-learn on Debian

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to install `scikit-learn` with `pip` on a `Debian Squeeze` workstation to which I don't have root access. Apparently, the workstation administrator here is getting tired of my frequent package installation requests every week, so I'd prefer to finish it in one shot. What `Debian Squeeze` packages exactly do I need in order to install `scikit-learn`? It appears to me that `liblapack-dev` and `libblas-dev` are neccessary. Is there anything else missing?

Comment: Well you could forward the list from the official installation instructions? http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html#getting-the-dependencies - I would expect them to include all you need.

Comment: @Gjallar Doesn't `libopenblas` seem to have some issues in parallel processing? I prefer not to use it.

Comment: @chenaren: indeed, OpenBLAS doesn't play nicely with Python's multiprocessing.

Answer (score 2):

The exact list of dependencies is written in the the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html#getting-the-dependencies).

scikit-learn is available in recent versions of Debian, so if you want to install all the scikit-learn build dependencies at once you can just do:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-sklearn
```

Also the [Neuro Debian APT repository](http://neuro.debian.net/) is updated at each scikit-learn release, so that you can get debian packages for the latest versions from there.

Comment: I prefer to be able to `pip install` it.

Comment: If you install all the build deps with `apt-get build-dep` then pip install should work.